# Finding the max path sum of a node tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, nodes

I'm trying to write a program that can build a node tree from a file and then find the maximum path sum of it. By path sum, I mean the sum of the values of nodes along a given top to bottom traverse.

I have a working program, but it isn't nearly fast enough, as I am supposed to be able to solve a tree with a depth of 100 within 10 seconds.

I'm hoping someone can give me pointers on how to optimize the run time, since it starts to get really slow after a tree depth of about 20.

NOTE: I'm not dealing with a regular a binary tree, the trees are formatted as follows.

For example, given the tree

```
      12 
    20  30
  50  07  30
20  60  15  42
```

The nodes on the maximum sum path would be 12 20 50 60, have a traverse path of: LLR, and the sum would equal 142.

My current program:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>  
    #include <math.h>
    #include <string.h>  
    #include <fstream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;

    struct node
    {
        int value;
        int depth;
        int index;
        struct node *left;
        struct node *right;
    };


    node * newNode(int value, int depth, int index)
    {
        node *temp = new node;
        temp->value  = value;
        temp->depth  = depth;
        temp->index  = index;
        temp->left  = temp->right = NULL;
        return (temp);
    }



    struct node * vec_to_tree(vector<int> arr)
    {
        node *newNode1;
        node *root;
        vector<node*> node_list;
        int i=0;
        int depth=1;

        root = newNode(arr[0],depth,i);;
        int size = arr.size();

        //how to save current index? i I guess.
        root = newNode(arr[0],depth,i);
        node_list.push_back(root);

        while(!node_list.empty())
        {


            newNode1 = node_list.front();
            node_list.erase(node_list.begin());

            //do i need to keep track of the index?
            //i = newNode->index;
            depth = newNode1->depth;

            //may need to double check on this one lol
            if(depth + i + 1 >= size)
                break;

            newNode1->left = newNode(arr[depth+i],depth+1,depth+i);
            node_list.push_back(newNode1->left);


            if(depth+i+2 >= size)
                break;

            newNode1->right = newNode(arr[depth+i+1],depth+1,depth+i+1);
            node_list.push_back(newNode1->right);

            i++;
            //we have 
            for(int j=0;j<depth-1;j++)
            {
              node *newNode2 = node_list.front();
               node_list.erase(node_list.begin());

               //assign newNode2's left child to newNode's right child 
               //this means we don't want to push it back onto the node_list
               newNode2->left= newNode1->right;

               newNode2->right = newNode(arr[depth+i+1],depth+1,depth+i+1);
               node_list.push_back(newNode2->right);

               newNode1=newNode2;
               i++;
            }

        }
        return root;
    }


    vector<int> readFileIntoVector(string fileName)
    {
        vector<int> data;

        // Replace 'Plop' with your file name.
        ifstream file(fileName);

        std::string   line;
        // Read one line at a time into the variable line:
        while(getline(file, line))
        {
            //do we really need this?
            //vector<int> lineData;

            stringstream lineStream(line);

            int value;
            // Read an integer at a time from the line
            while(lineStream >> value)
            {
                // Add the integers from a line to a 1D array (vector)
                data.push_back(value);
            }
        }
        file.close();

        return data;
    }


    // A utility function that prints all nodes
    // on the path from root to target_leaf
    void printPath (struct node *root, string path)
    {
        struct node * pNode = root;
        // base case
        if (root == NULL)
        {
            cout << "tree empty" << endl;
            return ;
        }
        if (path.empty())
        {
            cout << "string empty" << endl;
            return ;
        }

        cout << pNode->value << " ";

        for(int i =0; i<path.size();i++)
        {
            if(path[i] == 'L')
            {
                cout << pNode->left->value << " ";
                pNode= pNode->left;
            }
            else if(path[i] == 'R')
            {
                cout << pNode->right->value << " ";
                pNode= pNode->right;
            }
        }

        return ;
    }

    // This function sets the target_leaf_ref to refer the leaf node of the maximum path sum.  Also, returns the max_sum using max_sum_ref
    int getTargetLeaf (struct node *node, int *max_sum_ref, int curr_sum, string *path_ref, string curr_path, struct node **target_leaf_ref)
    {

        if (node == NULL)
        {
            curr_path.pop_back();
            return 1;
        }

        // Update current sum to hold sum of nodes on pathfrom root to this node
        curr_sum = curr_sum + node->value; 

        // If this is a leaf node and path to this node has maximum sum so far, then make this node target_leaf
        if (node->left == NULL && node->right == NULL)
        {
            if (curr_sum > *max_sum_ref)
            {
                *max_sum_ref = curr_sum;
                *path_ref= curr_path;
                *target_leaf_ref = node;
            }
        }

        // If this is not a leaf node, then recur down  to find the 
        int result = getTargetLeaf (node->left, max_sum_ref, curr_sum, path_ref, curr_path.insert(curr_path.size(),"L"), target_leaf_ref);
        if(result == 0)//result 0 is if its a leaf node
        {
            //the path keeps getting messed up. 
            curr_path.pop_back();
        };
        result = getTargetLeaf (node->right, max_sum_ref, curr_sum, path_ref,curr_path.insert(curr_path.size(),"R"), target_leaf_ref);

        return 0;
    }



    // Returns the maximum sum and prints the nodes on max sum path
    int maxSumPath (struct node *node)
    {
        // base case
        if (node == NULL)
            return 0;

        struct node *target_leaf;


        int max_sum = INT_MIN;
        string path = "";

        // find the target leaf and maximum sum
        getTargetLeaf (node, &max_sum, 0, &path,"", &target_leaf);

        // print the path from root to the target leaf
        printPath (node,path);

        cout << endl << "traverse path : " << path << endl;
        return max_sum;  // return maximum sum
    }

    int main()
    {
        struct node *treeRoot;
        int arr[] = { 2, 3, 4, 6,9,1 };
        vector<int> vec (arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) );

        cout << "printing test vector" <<endl;
        for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << *i << ' ';

        cout << endl;
        //{2,3,4,6,9,1};

        treeRoot = vec_to_tree(vec);

        cout << "Following are the nodes on the maximum sum path" << endl;
        int sum = maxSumPath(treeRoot);
        cout << "Sum of the nodes is " << sum << endl;


        cout << "Now lets try to get the largest path sum from the tree in the small file" << endl;
        vector<int> fileData2 = readFileIntoVector("GG-test-tree2.txt");

        cout << "printing vector" <<endl;
        for (vector<int>::const_iterator i = fileData2.begin(); i != fileData2.end(); ++i)
        cout << *i << ' ';

        treeRoot = vec_to_tree(fileData2);

        cout << endl << "Following are the nodes on the maximum sum path" << endl;

        sum = maxSumPath(treeRoot);

        cout << "Sum of the nodes is " << sum << endl;

        cout << endl << endl <<endl;

        cout << "Now to get the largest path sum from the tree in file" << endl;
        vector<int> fileData = readFileIntoVector("GG-test-tree.txt");

        cout << "printing vector" <<endl;
        for (vector<int>::const_iterator i = fileData.begin(); i != fileData.end(); ++i)
        cout << *i << ' ';

        treeRoot = vec_to_tree(fileData);

        cout << endl << "Following are the nodes on the maximum sum path" << endl;

        sum = maxSumPath(treeRoot);

        cout << "Sum of the nodes is" << sum << endl;

        return 0;
    }


    //sample tree
    /*
    59
    73 41
    51 40 08 
    26 53 06 34
    10 51 87 86 81
    61 95 66 57 25 68
    91 81 80 38 92 67 73
    30 28 51 76 81 18 75 44
    84 14 95 87 62 81 17 78 58
    21 46 71 58 02 79 62 39 31 09
    56 34 35 53 78 31 81 18 90 93 15
    78 53 04 21 84 93 32 13 97 11 37 51
    45 03 81 79 05 18 78 86 13 30 63 99 95
    39 87 96 28 03 38 42 17 82 87 58 07 22 57
    06 17 51 17 07 93 09 07 75 97 95 78 87 08 53
    67 66 59 60 88 99 94 65 55 77 55 34 27 53 78 28
    76 40 41 04 87 16 09 42 75 69 23 97 30 60 10 79 87
    12 10 44 26 21 36 32 84 98 60 13 12 36 16 63 31 91 35
    70 39 06 05 55 27 38 48 28 22 34 35 62 62 15 14 94 89 86
    66 56 68 84 96 21 34 34 34 81 62 40 65 54 62 05 98 03 02 60
    38 89 46 37 99 54 34 53 36 14 70 26 02 90 45 13 31 61 83 73 47
    36 10 63 96 60 49 41 05 37 42 14 58 84 93 96 17 09 43 05 43 06 59
    66 57 87 57 61 28 37 51 84 73 79 15 39 95 88 87 43 39 11 86 77 74 18
    54 42 05 79 30 49 99 73 46 37 50 02 45 09 54 52 27 95 27 65 19 45 26 45
    71 39 17 78 76 29 52 90 18 99 78 19 35 62 71 19 23 65 93 85 49 33 75 09 02
    33 24 47 61 60 55 32 88 57 55 91 54 46 57 07 77 98 52 80 99 24 25 46 78 79 05
    92 09 13 55 10 67 26 78 76 82 63 49 51 31 24 68 05 57 07 54 69 21 67 43 17 63 12
    24 59 06 08 98 74 66 26 61 60 13 03 09 09 24 30 71 08 88 70 72 70 29 90 11 82 41 34
    66 82 67 04 36 60 92 77 91 85 62 49 59 61 30 90 29 94 26 41 89 04 53 22 83 41 09 74 90
    48 28 26 37 28 52 77 26 51 32 18 98 79 36 62 13 17 08 19 54 89 29 73 68 42 14 08 16 70 37
    37 60 69 70 72 71 09 59 13 60 38 13 57 36 09 30 43 89 30 39 15 02 44 73 05 73 26 63 56 86 12
    55 55 85 50 62 99 84 77 28 85 03 21 27 22 19 26 82 69 54 04 13 07 85 14 01 15 70 59 89 95 10 19
    04 09 31 92 91 38 92 86 98 75 21 05 64 42 62 84 36 20 73 42 21 23 22 51 51 79 25 45 85 53 03 43 22
    75 63 02 49 14 12 89 14 60 78 92 16 44 82 38 30 72 11 46 52 90 27 08 65 78 03 85 41 57 79 39 52 33 48
    78 27 56 56 39 13 19 43 86 72 58 95 39 07 04 34 21 98 39 15 39 84 89 69 84 46 37 57 59 35 59 50 26 15 93
    42 89 36 27 78 91 24 11 17 41 05 94 07 69 51 96 03 96 47 90 90 45 91 20 50 56 10 32 36 49 04 53 85 92 25 65
    52 09 61 30 61 97 66 21 96 92 98 90 06 34 96 60 32 69 68 33 75 84 18 31 71 50 84 63 03 03 19 11 28 42 75 45 45
    61 31 61 68 96 34 49 39 05 71 76 59 62 67 06 47 96 99 34 21 32 47 52 07 71 60 42 72 94 56 82 83 84 40 94 87 82 46
    01 20 60 14 17 38 26 78 66 81 45 95 18 51 98 81 48 16 53 88 37 52 69 95 72 93 22 34 98 20 54 27 73 61 56 63 60 34 63
    93 42 94 83 47 61 27 51 79 79 45 01 44 73 31 70 83 42 88 25 53 51 30 15 65 94 80 44 61 84 12 77 02 62 02 65 94 42 14 94
    32 73 09 67 68 29 74 98 10 19 85 48 38 31 85 67 53 93 93 77 47 67 39 72 94 53 18 43 77 40 78 32 29 59 24 06 02 83 50 60 66
    32 01 44 30 16 51 15 81 98 15 10 62 86 79 50 62 45 60 70 38 31 85 65 61 64 06 69 84 14 22 56 43 09 48 66 69 83 91 60 40 36 61
    92 48 22 99 15 95 64 43 01 16 94 02 99 19 17 69 11 58 97 56 89 31 77 45 67 96 12 73 08 20 36 47 81 44 50 64 68 85 40 81 85 52 09
    91 35 92 45 32 84 62 15 19 64 21 66 06 01 52 80 62 59 12 25 88 28 91 50 40 16 22 99 92 79 87 51 21 77 74 77 07 42 38 42 74 83 02 05
    46 19 77 66 24 18 05 32 02 84 31 99 92 58 96 72 91 36 62 99 55 29 53 42 12 37 26 58 89 50 66 19 82 75 12 48 24 87 91 85 02 07 03 76 86
    99 98 84 93 07 17 33 61 92 20 66 60 24 66 40 30 67 05 37 29 24 96 03 27 70 62 13 04 45 47 59 88 43 20 66 15 46 92 30 04 71 66 78 70 53 99
    67 60 38 06 88 04 17 72 10 99 71 07 42 25 54 05 26 64 91 50 45 71 06 30 67 48 69 82 08 56 80 67 18 46 66 63 01 20 08 80 47 07 91 16 03 79 87
    18 54 78 49 80 48 77 40 68 23 60 88 58 80 33 57 11 69 55 53 64 02 94 49 60 92 16 35 81 21 82 96 25 24 96 18 02 05 49 03 50 77 06 32 84 27 18 38
    68 01 50 04 03 21 42 94 53 24 89 05 92 26 52 36 68 11 85 01 04 42 02 45 15 06 50 04 53 73 25 74 81 88 98 21 67 84 79 97 99 20 95 04 40 46 02 58 87
    94 10 02 78 88 52 21 03 88 60 06 53 49 71 20 91 12 65 07 49 21 22 11 41 58 99 36 16 09 48 17 24 52 36 23 15 72 16 84 56 02 99 43 76 81 71 29 39 49 17
    64 39 59 84 86 16 17 66 03 09 43 06 64 18 63 29 68 06 23 07 87 14 26 35 17 12 98 41 53 64 78 18 98 27 28 84 80 67 75 62 10 11 76 90 54 10 05 54 41 39 66
    43 83 18 37 32 31 52 29 95 47 08 76 35 11 04 53 35 43 31 12 52 57 12 36 20 39 40 55 78 44 07 31 38 26 08 15 56 88 86 01 52 62 10 24 32 05 60 65 53 28 57 99
    03 50 03 52 07 73 49 92 66 80 01 46 08 67 25 36 73 93 07 42 25 53 13 96 76 83 87 90 54 89 78 22 78 91 73 51 69 09 79 94 83 53 09 40 69 62 10 79 49 47 03 81 30
    71 54 73 33 51 76 59 54 79 37 56 45 84 17 62 21 98 69 41 95 65 24 39 37 62 03 24 48 54 64 46 82 71 78 33 67 09 16 96 68 52 74 79 68 32 21 13 78 96 60 09 69 20 36
    73 26 21 44 46 38 17 83 65 98 07 23 52 46 61 97 33 13 60 31 70 15 36 77 31 58 56 93 75 68 21 36 69 53 90 75 25 82 39 50 65 94 29 30 11 33 11 13 96 02 56 47 07 49 02
    76 46 73 30 10 20 60 70 14 56 34 26 37 39 48 24 55 76 84 91 39 86 95 61 50 14 53 93 64 67 37 31 10 84 42 70 48 20 10 72 60 61 84 79 69 65 99 73 89 25 85 48 92 56 97 16
    03 14 80 27 22 30 44 27 67 75 79 32 51 54 81 29 65 14 19 04 13 82 04 91 43 40 12 52 29 99 07 76 60 25 01 07 61 71 37 92 40 47 99 66 57 01 43 44 22 40 53 53 09 69 26 81 07
    49 80 56 90 93 87 47 13 75 28 87 23 72 79 32 18 27 20 28 10 37 59 21 18 70 04 79 96 03 31 45 71 81 06 14 18 17 05 31 50 92 79 23 47 09 39 47 91 43 54 69 47 42 95 62 46 32 85
    37 18 62 85 87 28 64 05 77 51 47 26 30 65 05 70 65 75 59 80 42 52 25 20 44 10 92 17 71 95 52 14 77 13 24 55 11 65 26 91 01 30 63 15 49 48 41 17 67 47 03 68 20 90 98 32 04 40 68
    90 51 58 60 06 55 23 68 05 19 76 94 82 36 96 43 38 90 87 28 33 83 05 17 70 83 96 93 06 04 78 47 80 06 23 84 75 23 87 72 99 14 50 98 92 38 90 64 61 58 76 94 36 66 87 80 51 35 61 38
    57 95 64 06 53 36 82 51 40 33 47 14 07 98 78 65 39 58 53 06 50 53 04 69 40 68 36 69 75 78 75 60 03 32 39 24 74 47 26 90 13 40 44 71 90 76 51 24 36 50 25 45 70 80 61 80 61 43 90 64 11
    18 29 86 56 68 42 79 10 42 44 30 12 96 18 23 18 52 59 02 99 67 46 60 86 43 38 55 17 44 93 42 21 55 14 47 34 55 16 49 24 23 29 96 51 55 10 46 53 27 92 27 46 63 57 30 65 43 27 21 20 24 83
    81 72 93 19 69 52 48 01 13 83 92 69 20 48 69 59 20 62 05 42 28 89 90 99 32 72 84 17 08 87 36 03 60 31 36 36 81 26 97 36 48 54 56 56 27 16 91 08 23 11 87 99 33 47 02 14 44 73 70 99 43 35 33
    90 56 61 86 56 12 70 59 63 32 01 15 81 47 71 76 95 32 65 80 54 70 34 51 40 45 33 04 64 55 78 68 88 47 31 47 68 87 03 84 23 44 89 72 35 08 31 76 63 26 90 85 96 67 65 91 19 14 17 86 04 71 32 95
    37 13 04 22 64 37 37 28 56 62 86 33 07 37 10 44 52 82 52 06 19 52 57 75 90 26 91 24 06 21 14 67 76 30 46 14 35 89 89 41 03 64 56 97 87 63 22 34 03 79 17 45 11 53 25 56 96 61 23 18 63 31 37 37 47
    77 23 26 70 72 76 77 04 28 64 71 69 14 85 96 54 95 48 06 62 99 83 86 77 97 75 71 66 30 19 57 90 33 01 60 61 14 12 90 99 32 77 56 41 18 14 87 49 10 14 90 64 18 50 21 74 14 16 88 05 45 73 82 47 74 44
    22 97 41 13 34 31 54 61 56 94 03 24 59 27 98 77 04 09 37 40 12 26 87 09 71 70 07 18 64 57 80 21 12 71 83 94 60 39 73 79 73 19 97 32 64 29 41 07 48 84 85 67 12 74 95 20 24 52 41 67 56 61 29 93 35 72 69
    72 23 63 66 01 11 07 30 52 56 95 16 65 26 83 90 50 74 60 18 16 48 43 77 37 11 99 98 30 94 91 26 62 73 45 12 87 73 47 27 01 88 66 99 21 41 95 80 02 53 23 32 61 48 32 43 43 83 14 66 95 91 19 81 80 67 25 88
    08 62 32 18 92 14 83 71 37 96 11 83 39 99 05 16 23 27 10 67 02 25 44 11 55 31 46 64 41 56 44 74 26 81 51 31 45 85 87 09 81 95 22 28 76 69 46 48 64 87 67 76 27 89 31 11 74 16 62 03 60 94 42 47 09 34 94 93 72
    56 18 90 18 42 17 42 32 14 86 06 53 33 95 99 35 29 15 44 20 49 59 25 54 34 59 84 21 23 54 35 90 78 16 93 13 37 88 54 19 86 67 68 55 66 84 65 42 98 37 87 56 33 28 58 38 28 38 66 27 52 21 81 15 08 22 97 32 85 27
    91 53 40 28 13 34 91 25 01 63 50 37 22 49 71 58 32 28 30 18 68 94 23 83 63 62 94 76 80 41 90 22 82 52 29 12 18 56 10 08 35 14 37 57 23 65 67 40 72 39 93 39 70 89 40 34 07 46 94 22 20 05 53 64 56 30 05 56 61 88 27
    23 95 11 12 37 69 68 24 66 10 87 70 43 50 75 07 62 41 83 58 95 93 89 79 45 39 02 22 05 22 95 43 62 11 68 29 17 40 26 44 25 71 87 16 70 85 19 25 59 94 90 41 41 80 61 70 55 60 84 33 95 76 42 63 15 09 03 40 38 12 03 32
    09 84 56 80 61 55 85 97 16 94 82 94 98 57 84 30 84 48 93 90 71 05 95 90 73 17 30 98 40 64 65 89 07 79 09 19 56 36 42 30 23 69 73 72 07 05 27 61 24 31 43 48 71 84 21 28 26 65 65 59 65 74 77 20 10 81 61 84 95 08 52 23 70
    49 81 28 09 98 51 67 64 35 51 59 36 92 82 77 65 80 24 72 53 22 07 27 10 21 28 30 22 48 82 80 48 56 20 14 43 18 25 50 95 90 31 77 08 09 48 44 80 90 22 93 45 82 17 13 96 25 26 08 73 34 99 06 49 24 06 83 51 40 14 15 10 25 01
    54 25 10 81 30 64 24 74 75 80 36 75 82 60 22 69 72 91 45 67 03 62 79 54 89 74 44 83 64 96 66 73 44 30 74 50 37 05 09 97 70 01 60 46 37 91 39 75 75 18 58 52 72 78 51 81 86 52 08 97 01 46 43 66 98 62 81 18 70 93 73 08 32 46 34
    96 80 82 07 59 71 92 53 19 20 88 66 03 26 26 10 24 27 50 82 94 73 63 08 51 33 22 45 19 13 58 33 90 15 22 50 36 13 55 06 35 47 82 52 33 61 36 27 28 46 98 14 73 20 73 32 16 26 80 53 47 66 76 38 94 45 02 01 22 52 47 96 64 58 52 39
    88 46 23 39 74 63 81 64 20 90 33 33 76 55 58 26 10 46 42 26 74 74 12 83 32 43 09 02 73 55 86 54 85 34 28 23 29 79 91 62 47 41 82 87 99 22 48 90 20 05 96 75 95 04 43 28 81 39 81 01 28 42 78 25 39 77 90 57 58 98 17 36 73 22 63 74 51
    29 39 74 94 95 78 64 24 38 86 63 87 93 06 70 92 22 16 80 64 29 52 20 27 23 50 14 13 87 15 72 96 81 22 08 49 72 30 70 24 79 31 16 64 59 21 89 34 96 91 48 76 43 53 88 01 57 80 23 81 90 79 58 01 80 87 17 99 86 90 72 63 32 69 14 28 88 69
    37 17 71 95 56 93 71 35 43 45 04 98 92 94 84 96 11 30 31 27 31 60 92 03 48 05 98 91 86 94 35 90 90 08 48 19 33 28 68 37 59 26 65 96 50 68 22 07 09 49 34 31 77 49 43 06 75 17 81 87 61 79 52 26 27 72 29 50 07 98 86 01 17 10 46 64 24 18 56
    51 30 25 94 88 85 79 91 40 33 63 84 49 67 98 92 15 26 75 19 82 05 18 78 65 93 61 48 91 43 59 41 70 51 22 15 92 81 67 91 46 98 11 11 65 31 66 10 98 65 83 21 05 56 05 98 73 67 46 74 69 34 08 30 05 52 07 98 32 95 30 94 65 50 24 63 28 81 99 57
    19 23 61 36 09 89 71 98 65 17 30 29 89 26 79 74 94 11 44 48 97 54 81 55 39 66 69 45 28 47 13 86 15 76 74 70 84 32 36 33 79 20 78 14 41 47 89 28 81 05 99 66 81 86 38 26 06 25 13 60 54 55 23 53 27 05 89 25 23 11 13 54 59 54 56 34 16 24 53 44 06
    13 40 57 72 21 15 60 08 04 19 11 98 34 45 09 97 86 71 03 15 56 19 15 44 97 31 90 04 87 87 76 08 12 30 24 62 84 28 12 85 82 53 99 52 13 94 06 65 97 86 09 50 94 68 69 74 30 67 87 94 63 07 78 27 80 36 69 41 06 92 32 78 37 82 30 05 18 87 99 72 19 99
    44 20 55 77 69 91 27 31 28 81 80 27 02 07 97 23 95 98 12 25 75 29 47 71 07 47 78 39 41 59 27 76 13 15 66 61 68 35 69 86 16 53 67 63 99 85 41 56 08 28 33 40 94 76 90 85 31 70 24 65 84 65 99 82 19 25 54 37 21 46 33 02 52 99 51 33 26 04 87 02 08 18 96
    54 42 61 45 91 06 64 79 80 82 32 16 83 63 42 49 19 78 65 97 40 42 14 61 49 34 04 18 25 98 59 30 82 72 26 88 54 36 21 75 03 88 99 53 46 51 55 78 22 94 34 40 68 87 84 25 30 76 25 08 92 84 42 61 40 38 09 99 40 23 29 39 46 55 10 90 35 84 56 70 63 23 91 39
    52 92 03 71 89 07 09 37 68 66 58 20 44 92 51 56 13 71 79 99 26 37 02 06 16 67 36 52 58 16 79 73 56 60 59 27 44 77 94 82 20 50 98 33 09 87 94 37 40 83 64 83 58 85 17 76 53 02 83 52 22 27 39 20 48 92 45 21 09 42 24 23 12 37 52 28 50 78 79 20 86 62 73 20 59
    54 96 80 15 91 90 99 70 10 09 58 90 93 50 81 99 54 38 36 10 30 11 35 84 16 45 82 18 11 97 36 43 96 79 97 65 40 48 23 19 17 31 64 52 65 65 37 32 65 76 99 79 34 65 79 27 55 33 03 01 33 27 61 28 66 08 04 70 49 46 48 83 01 45 19 96 13 81 14 21 31 79 93 85 50 05
    92 92 48 84 59 98 31 53 23 27 15 22 79 95 24 76 05 79 16 93 97 89 38 89 42 83 02 88 94 95 82 21 01 97 48 39 31 78 09 65 50 56 97 61 01 07 65 27 21 23 14 15 80 97 44 78 49 35 33 45 81 74 34 05 31 57 09 38 94 07 69 54 69 32 65 68 46 68 78 90 24 28 49 51 45 86 35
    41 63 89 76 87 31 86 09 46 14 87 82 22 29 47 16 13 10 70 72 82 95 48 64 58 43 13 75 42 69 21 12 67 13 64 85 58 23 98 09 37 76 05 22 31 12 66 50 29 99 86 72 45 25 10 28 19 06 90 43 29 31 67 79 46 25 74 14 97 35 76 37 65 46 23 82 06 22 30 76 93 66 94 17 96 13 20 72
    63 40 78 08 52 09 90 41 70 28 36 14 46 44 85 96 24 52 58 15 87 37 05 98 99 39 13 61 76 38 44 99 83 74 90 22 53 80 56 98 30 51 63 39 44 30 91 91 04 22 27 73 17 35 53 18 35 45 54 56 27 78 48 13 69 36 44 38 71 25 30 56 15 22 73 43 32 69 59 25 93 83 45 11 34 94 44 39 92
    12 36 56 88 13 96 16 12 55 54 11 47 19 78 17 17 68 81 77 51 42 55 99 85 66 27 81 79 93 42 65 61 69 74 14 01 18 56 12 01 58 37 91 22 42 66 83 25 19 04 96 41 25 45 18 69 96 88 36 93 10 12 98 32 44 83 83 04 72 91 04 27 73 07 34 37 71 60 59 31 01 54 54 44 96 93 83 36 04 45
    30 18 22 20 42 96 65 79 17 41 55 69 94 81 29 80 91 31 85 25 47 26 43 49 02 99 34 67 99 76 16 14 15 93 08 32 99 44 61 77 67 50 43 55 87 55 53 72 17 46 62 25 50 99 73 05 93 48 17 31 70 80 59 09 44 59 45 13 74 66 58 94 87 73 16 14 85 38 74 99 64 23 79 28 71 42 20 37 82 31 23
    51 96 39 65 46 71 56 13 29 68 53 86 45 33 51 49 12 91 21 21 76 85 02 17 98 15 46 12 60 21 88 30 92 83 44 59 42 50 27 88 46 86 94 73 45 54 23 24 14 10 94 21 20 34 23 51 04 83 99 75 90 63 60 16 22 33 83 70 11 32 10 50 29 30 83 46 11 05 31 17 86 42 49 01 44 63 28 60 07 78 95 40
    44 61 89 59 04 49 51 27 69 71 46 76 44 04 09 34 56 39 15 06 94 91 75 90 65 27 56 23 74 06 23 33 36 69 14 39 05 34 35 57 33 22 76 46 56 10 61 65 98 09 16 69 04 62 65 18 99 76 49 18 72 66 73 83 82 40 76 31 89 91 27 88 17 35 41 35 32 51 32 67 52 68 74 85 80 57 07 11 62 66 47 22 67
    65 37 19 97 26 17 16 24 24 17 50 37 64 82 24 36 32 11 68 34 69 31 32 89 79 93 96 68 49 90 14 23 04 04 67 99 81 74 70 74 36 92 68 09 64 39 88 35 54 89 96 58 66 27 88 97 32 14 06 35 78 20 71 06 85 66 57 02 58 91 72 05 29 56 73 48 86 52 09 93 22 57 79 42 12 01 31 68 17 59 63 76 07 77
    73 81 14 13 17 20 11 09 01 83 08 85 91 70 84 63 62 77 37 07 47 01 59 95 39 69 39 21 99 09 87 02 97 16 92 36 74 71 90 66 33 73 73 75 52 91 11 12 26 53 05 26 26 48 61 50 90 65 01 87 42 47 74 35 22 73 24 26 56 70 52 05 48 41 31 18 83 27 21 39 80 85 26 08 44 02 71 07 63 22 05 52 19 08 20
    17 25 21 11 72 93 33 49 64 23 53 82 03 13 91 65 85 02 40 05 42 31 77 42 05 36 06 54 04 58 07 76 87 83 25 57 66 12 74 33 85 37 74 32 20 69 03 97 91 68 82 44 19 14 89 28 85 85 80 53 34 87 58 98 88 78 48 65 98 40 11 57 10 67 70 81 60 79 74 72 97 59 79 47 30 20 54 80 89 91 14 05 33 36 79 39
    60 85 59 39 60 07 57 76 77 92 06 35 15 72 23 41 45 52 95 18 64 79 86 53 56 31 69 11 91 31 84 50 44 82 22 81 41 40 30 42 30 91 48 94 74 76 64 58 74 25 96 57 14 19 03 99 28 83 15 75 99 01 89 85 79 50 03 95 32 67 44 08 07 41 62 64 29 20 14 76 26 55 48 71 69 66 19 72 44 25 14 01 48 74 12 98 07
    64 66 84 24 18 16 27 48 20 14 47 69 30 86 48 40 23 16 61 21 51 50 26 47 35 33 91 28 76 64 43 68 04 79 51 08 19 60 52 95 06 68 46 86 35 97 27 58 04 65 30 58 99 12 12 75 91 39 50 31 42 64 70 04 46 07 98 73 98 93 37 89 77 91 64 71 64 65 66 21 78 62 81 74 42 20 83 70 73 95 78 45 92 27 34 53 71 15
    30 11 85 31 34 71 13 48 05 14 44 03 19 67 23 73 19 57 06 90 94 72 57 69 81 62 59 68 88 57 55 69 49 13 07 87 97 80 89 05 71 05 05 26 38 40 16 62 45 99 18 38 98 24 21 26 62 74 69 04 85 57 77 35 58 67 91 79 79 57 86 28 66 34 72 51 76 78 36 95 63 90 08 78 47 63 45 31 22 70 52 48 79 94 15 77 61 67 68
    23 33 44 81 80 92 93 75 94 88 23 61 39 76 22 03 28 94 32 06 49 65 41 34 18 23 08 47 62 60 03 63 33 13 80 52 31 54 73 43 70 26 16 69 57 87 83 31 03 93 70 81 47 95 77 44 29 68 39 51 56 59 63 07 25 70 07 77 43 53 64 03 94 42 95 39 18 01 66 21 16 97 20 50 90 16 70 10 95 69 29 06 25 61 41 26 15 59 63 35
    */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is top-down: It starts from the root. You could be more efficient if you start from the leaves.

You can store the leaves in a `vector` of `pair<int, path_to_the_max>`.

Then for each couple of leaves indexed by `i` and `i+1`, you choose the max and add their parent in the `int` part; don't forget to push this choice in the `path_to_the_max` part. The result can be stored in the same vector at index `i`.

Then you go up with the new vector. You are now at the level of the parent of the leaves.

You can iterate this process until your vector contains only one element. The successive choices of max is your solution - it is the second element of the pair of the element.

The initial algorithm should use `2 ** (depth-1)` comparisons.
This algorithm should work with `(depth * (depth-1))/2` comparisons.

*UPDATE*

Here is how the bottom-up algorithm works on your example - see the code below.

```
         12 
       20  30
     50  07  30
   20  60  15  42

current_nodes  20    60    15    42
maxAtDepth     20,0  60,0  15,0  42,0
               |    / |   / |   /
next iterate   m=60   m=60  m=42
current_nodes  50      07    30
maxAtDepth     110,1   67,0  72,1
               |    /  |   /
next iterate   m=110   m=72
current_nodes  20      30
maxAtDepth     130,01  102,10
               |      /
next iterate    m=130
current_nodes  12
maxAtDepth     142,001

result = 142, path = 001 = left-left-right
```

Here is some modifications on your code - not tested, nor debugged

```
struct node
{
    int value;
    ...
    struct node *parent_left; // new
    struct node *parent_right; // new
};

struct node * vec_to_tree(vector<int> arr)
{ ...
        newNode1->left = newNode(arr[depth+i],depth+1,depth+i);
        newNode1->left->parent_right = newNode1; // new
  ...
        newNode1->right = newNode(arr[depth+i+1],depth+1,depth+i+1);
        newNode1->right->parent_left = newNode1; // new
  ...
           newNode2->left= newNode1->right;
           newNode2->left->parent_right = newNode2; // new
           newNode2->right = newNode(arr[depth+i+1],depth+1,depth+i+1);
           newNode2->right->parent_left = newNode2; // new
}

class PathToMax {
  public:
   class BitAccess {
     private:
      unsigned* _cell;
      int _index;
     public:
      BitAccess(unsigned* cell, int index) : _cell(cell), _index(index) {}
      operator bool() const { return (*_cell >> _index) & 1U; }
      BitAccess& operator=(bool val)
         { *_cell &= ~(1U << _index); *_cell |= (val << _index); return *this; } 
   };

  private:
   unsigned _path[10]; // depth <= 320

  public:
   PathToMax() { for (int i = 0; i<10; ++i) _path[i] =0; }

   BitAccess operator[](int index)
      {  assert(index < (int) (10*sizeof(unsigned)*8));
         return BitAccess(&_path[index / (sizeof(unsigned)*8)], index % (sizeof(unsigned)*8));
      }
};

int maxSumPath (struct node *node, int depth)
{  
   typedef vector<std::pair<int, PathToMax> > MaxAtDepth;
   typedef vector<struct node*> NodesLevel;

   // go to the leaves
   NodesLevel current_nodes, next_nodes;
   current_nodes.push_back(node);
   for (int i = 0; i < depth; ++i) {
      next_nodes.clear();
      for (struct node* node : current_nodes)
         next_nodes.push_back(node->left); // test if NULL
      next_nodes.push_back(current_nodes.back()->right);
      current_nodes.swap(next_nodes);
   };

   // build initial maxAtDepth
   MaxAtDepth maxAtDepth;
   for (struct node* node : current_nodes)
      maxAtDepth.push_back(std::make_pair(node->value, PathToMax()));

   // apply the algorithm
   int inverse_depth = 0;
   while (maxAtDepth.size() > 1) {
      next_nodes.clear();
      MaxAtDepth upMaxAtDepth;

      MaxAtDepth::const_iterator iter_max = maxAtDepth.begin(),
                                 iter_max_next = maxAtDepth.begin() + 1,
                                 iter_max_end = maxAtDepth.end();
      NodesLevel::const_iterator iter = current_nodes.begin(),
                                 iter_next = current_nodes.begin() + 1,
                                 iter_end = current_nodes.end();
      for (; iter_next != iter_end; ++iter, ++iter_next, ++iter_max, ++iter_max_next) {
         assert((*iter)->parent_right == (*iter_next)->parent_left);
         next_nodes.push_back((*iter)->parent_right);
         assert(iter_max_next != iter_max_end);
         if ((*iter)->value >= (*iter_next)->value) {
            upMaxAtDepth.push_back(std::make_pair(
                  (*iter)->parent_right->value + iter_max->first,
                  iter_max->second));
            upMaxAtDepth.back().second[inverse_depth] = false /* left path */;
         }
         else {
            upMaxAtDepth.push_back(std::make_pair(
                  (*iter_next)->parent_left->value + iter_max_next->first,
                  iter_max_next->second));
            upMaxAtDepth.back().second[inverse_depth] = true /* right path */;
         }
      };
      next_nodes.swap(current_nodes);
      maxAtDepth.swap(upMaxAtDepth);
      ++inverse_depth;
   };

   return maxAtDepth[0].first;
   // the path is in maxAtDepth[0].snd from index 0 to inverse_depth-1;
}
```

Note that your tree has memory leaks since the left node of a cell is shared the right node of its brother. This is not the case for the extremities at a given level. Since you have no garbage collector, in C++, you should know if you have the ownership on the substructures or not.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? I'm kind of confused about how to implement your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help Franck. 
Right now I'm tying in the code you gave me, but I'm still confused about what is going on in the PathToMax class, and I'm hitting a bit of a wall trying to resolve one error. What is PathToMax supposed to represent? In the diagram you drew, it held a sequence of 0s and 1s to represent left and right transitions.

The error I am getting when _cell is being called within BitAccess functions is: "expression must have integral or unscoped enum type". How do you do bit shifting operations on a pointer? I tried casting using uintptr_t

Comment: and I think uintptr_t casts to a const * or something because then I get the error expression must be a modifiable lvalue.

Comment: @ZachEllis: PathToMax is an optional class. You can comment it first; it just represent a path by a succession of 0 an 1: a 0 chooses the left son and a 1 chooses the right son. If you don't need the path for the result, you don't need it.

Comment: @ZachEllis: Sorry, I forgot many `*` in the code of my post. It should compile now.

Comment: Thanks again for your help Franck!

Comment: I got my program working without PathToMax.

I just saw that you corrected the compiler errors in your code, but did you run it on your machine?
When I tried to incorporate it I got an unhandled exception.
It's throwing the exception in the library where make_pair is defined.
 Any ideas? This isn't a big deal since the requirements of the program was to output the sum, but I want to know what's going on.

maxAtDepth.push_back(std::make_pair(node->value, PathToMax()));

Unhandled exception at 0x00BB52F2 in GP test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: @ZachEllis No, I have not run it. I will try to improve the code, maybe in replacing `PathToMax` by a `vector<bool>` which is simpler.

Comment: @ZachEllis : node was null in you try; I succeed in calling `maxSumPath` with `depth-1`, where `depth` is another result of `vec_to_tree`. `depth-1=2` in your first example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm understanding well the question, but if I am I'll post my answer here (please let me know if you meant something else in the question):

You can start from a root and do a recursive approach in `O(n)`, where `n` is the number of nodes on your tree.

Let's define `max_sum(node)` as the maximmum sum you can get from your current node only by going in depth (to the bottom). Now your function will be defined as (pseudocode here):

```
max_sum(node) {
    if (node.is_leaf()) {
        return node.value;
    }
    left_sum = max_sum(node.left_child);
    right_sum = max_sum(node.right_child);
    return max(left_sum, right_sum) + node.value;
}
```

As you can see, the maximmum value for the sum you can get for your current node is the maximmum value for both sons (left and right) + your current node's value. This works because you clearly choose the best you can get from going in depth from both of your sons.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but this seems to be giving me the same problem I was having before.